# Python: Round time (without date) to the nearest second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I keep seeing cases of datetime for this question but none only with the time.

I have a time column like this:

```
0   16:19:01.600000
1   16:20:02.700000
2          16:20:18
3   16:21:03.400000
4   16:21:49.200000
```

To round the time to seconds so it is 16:19:02, 16:20:03, and so on, I've tried to first convert the time column to datetime with the following code:

```
# Converting time to datetime (again)
pd.to_datetime(trip_28["time"], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

which returns:

```
unconverted data remains: .600000
```

Then the intention is to use:

```
# Rounding the time column to seconds
trip_28["time"] = trip_28["time"].dt.floor('1s')
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Makes more sense to me to convert this to timedelta,  not an actual date as the answers are suggesting: `pd.to_timedelta(df["time"]).dt.round('1s')`

Answer (score 1):

Try [pd.DatetimeIndex.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html#pandas-datetimeindex-round) with the frequency set to `S`

From the docs

```
pd.Series(rng).dt.round("H")
0   2018-01-01 12:00:00
1   2018-01-01 12:00:00
2   2018-01-01 12:00:00
```

Comment: I think the freq parameter should be "S", not "H"

Comment: That's what I said. The example is from the documentation to show the rounding

Answer (score 1):

Convert to datetime and round with `freq='S'`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.round(freq='S')
0   2021-08-03 16:19:02
1   2021-08-03 16:20:03
2   2021-08-03 16:20:18
3   2021-08-03 16:21:03
4   2021-08-03 16:21:49
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```